# Powershell remove extension for full path name (I don't want just filename)

Tags: powershell, file-extension

When searching, I was surprised that there were only answers for getting filename without extension but they discard path whereas I want to keep the path :

So is there a standard method for that or do I need to parse myself ?

Comment: So you want something like `c:\temp\myresume` for `c:\temp\myresume.pdf`?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? You say "Powershell Remove Extension", then say "getting filename without extension discarding path wheres I want to keep path"? Do you want the absolute path without the the extension?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala sorry I have rephrased now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note:

- This answer shows a solution for modifying a given path *string*.
- If you're dealing with [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instances as input, such as output by [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem), consider the solution in [Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68226652/45375).

It is not the most obvious solution, but it is concise, based on the [`[System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension) method:

```sh
PS> [IO.Path]::ChangeExtension('C:\path\to\some\file.txt', [NullString]::Value)

C:\path\to\some\file
```

What makes the solution obscure is the need to pass `[NullString]:Value` in order to pass a true `null` value to the .NET method - using `$null` does *not* work, because PowerShell treats it like `""`, i.e. the *empty string*,<sup>[1]</sup> which causes the method to *keep the `.`* part of the extension.

The slightly less obscure, but more verbose alternative is to trim the trailing `.` after the fact:

```sh
PS> [IO.Path]::ChangeExtension('C:\path\to\some\file.txt', '').TrimEnd('.')

C:\path\to\some\file
```

---

<sup>[1] By design, PowerShell doesn't let you store `$null` in string-typed variables, which means that a `[string]`-typed parameter variable contains the empty string by default and even passing or assigning `$null` is converted to the empty string. The [`[NullString]::Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Language.NullString.Value) singleton was introduced in v3 specifically to allow passing true `null` values to .NET APIs with `string`-typed parameters.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Join Directory and BaseName properties

```
Get-ChildItem -File | ForEach-Object {
    Join-Path $_.Directory $_.BaseName
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `-replace` operator to remove the extension from the `FullName` property value:

```
Get-ChildItem -File |ForEach-Object {
    $_.FullName -replace "$([regex]::Escape($_.Extension))$"
}
```